# Create an Index for a find() operation in a mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, indexing, find

I have a collection called posts in mongodb and I want to do a query with indexes in order to optimize the query. I want to do the next query:

```
db.posts.find().sort({ date: -1 })
```

My post documents is like:

```
{
_id: 'title',
author: 'Name of the author',
content: 'text text text',
tags: ['tag1', 'tag2'],
comments: ['c1', 'c2'],
date: '10-10-2014'
}
```

Do you have any idea to create an Index and optimize the query?

Comment: How about [the MongoDB docs about creating indices](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-index/)? And btw, you are missing the date field you want to sort your results by.

Comment: Note also that there's no `date` field in the document. Add that and put an index on `{ date : 1 }` and the query is optimized. It's still a full index scan though, since you have no query conditions.

Comment: How can I know wheter my query is optimized or not? I check with .explain() and that return the same "milli" value of 5 or 4 and in "nscannedObjects" : 1000,"nscanned" : 1000. Wich means that scan all the collection objects.

Comment: Well, this is since you don't actually query, but you return all documents. Mongod looks through all documents since it needs to check all documents for the (non existing) date field. My advice: Before you start optimizing your queries, you should refine your data model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .find() function has no arguments, therefore, query will need to access all documents in a collection.

If you use an index (up to this point), it will only introduce some overhead.

Your .sort() instruction requires that returned documents (the whole collection) should be sorted.
And this is a case, where you can benefit from an index:

```
db.posts.ensureIndex({date:1}) (or -1)
```

In this case, mongodb will read whole index, and then individually go for every document, but in sorted order.

When you run .explain(), if you see "BtreeCursor" then an index was used somehow (for find, sort, or both). Here is [how to read .explain() output](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#Explain-OutputFields)